# Mongo query must match 2 fields in 1 subset

Tags: mongodb, nested

I currently have the following dataset (simplified):

```
{  
    'component_id':1,  
    '_locales':[   
        {  
            'url': 'dutch',  
            'locale': 'nl_NL'  
        },  
        {  
            'url': 'english',  
            'locale': 'en_US'  
        }  
    ]  
} (etc more rows similar to this but unique urls)
```

Now I want to perform a query to see if for the locale 'en_US' the url 'english exists:

```
db.find({'_locales.locale':'en_US','_locales.url':'english'})
```

This indeed provides me with the dataset row. However if i want to check if for the locale 'nl_NL' the url 'english';

```
db.find({'_locales.locale':'nl_NL','_locales.url':'english'})
```

I still get the dataset back which I don't want because the query shoudln't match. As i only want it to match if the locale is nl_NL and in the same row the url is 'english'

I tried

```
 db.find({'_locales.locale':'en_US','_locales.$.url':'english'})
```

This didn't work, is there any way to do this at all? So that it matches 2 fields in 1 row instead 2 fields separately?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`$elemMatch`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch)

```
db.find({'_locales': { '$elemMatch': { 'locale': 'nl_NL', 'url': 'english' } }});
```

`$elemMatch` is used when a single element in an array must match the match expression. Otherwise (as you found), each criteria can match a different array element.

Comment: @WimWisselink: You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer solved your problem, then you can mark it as an accepted answer. This will keep your "accepted answer" ratio high, which is a good thing for you.